# Golang IMAP: moving messages to another folder

Tags: go, imap

I'm lost on where to look in the references to accomplish this; I've tried several iterations of code and each fails. Slightly edited, but enough to get the gist...

```
// Make connection
imConnection, err := imap.DialTLS(strAddress, nil)

// Defer disconnect
defer func(){
    imConnection.Logout(30*time.Second)
}

// Authenticate
imConnection.Login(strUname, strPass)

//Select the folder with messages I want to move
imConnection.Select(`[Gmail]\Movethese`, false)

// Create a set
set, _ = imap.NewSeqSet("1:*")

// It's my understanding that moving messages means copying them over, then
// deleting the original messages?
cmd, _ := imConnection.UIDCopy(set, `[Gmail]\Destination`)
```

This seems to silently fail. This to me looked like it should select everything in the "Movethese" folder and copy them to "Destination." What am I missing in properly copying them over? Is there a simple way to move individual messages that match a certain subject line string?

Also I wasn't sure if the source directory would have to be set to False for R/W when selected, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is importing the [github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap package](https://github.com/mxk/go-imap)

Comment: There are 5 calls in this code snippet that return error values.  Are you checking them in the actual code?  If so, are all of them returning nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add error checking to the two commands that name mailboxes; the backslash is a special character in source code so I expect gmail is giving you an error such as `No such mailbox: [Gmail]Movethese`.

Handling errors is generally a good idea, particularly in cases such as this, when you know there *is* an error somewhere.

BTW, the copy/delete sequence is a bit oldfashioned. Most IMAP servers support [UID MOVE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6851) as an atomic command these days, and IIRC gmail is among the supporters. Can't check now, though, so don't trust me.

Comment: @amt - Some background...yes, I was catching (most of) the errors in question. I started entering my actual source code for analysis in my question when I realized that I did have a mismatched slash (backslash vs forward slash) in my call to copy compared to my Select! I had slash blindness! It doesn't look like it was triggering an error or oddball response in the call...so I'm going to investigate how to better tease that reply from the server. But it solved my copy part of the equation! Thank you!

Comment: Re: UID move vs. copy/delete...I don't see a direct move function in the imap package? Either there would have to be a way to directly enter the raw command or the copy/delete method would have to do, I think...or maybe the copy/delete method is more backwards compatible/safer?